# Stochastic volatility estimation in R

Tags: volatility, programming, stochastic-volatility, estimation

Can anyone help me with the `stochvol` package in R? I estimated the volatilities using this package but I am not being able to understand how to download the estimated volatilities. I used `volplot` function to plot the volatilities but not understanding how to download that output.

I have used the following code. When I use the `volplot` function, estimated volatilities look very different compared to the ones when I try to extract the median values in the `m_export_oil` dataframe.

The data required is here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14r-_SxCvOG9-_tTNLgXWU-FPkx_8OYLh/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=118324139963698395675&rtpof=true&sd=true

```
library(stochvol)
library(xlsx)

set.seed(123)
oil_qtrly <- read.xlsx("oil_qtrly.xlsx", sheetIndex = 1L)
oil_qtrly$log_real_op <- log(oil_qtrly$real_price)


sv_model_oil <- svsample(oil_qtrly$log_real_op, priormu = c(-10, 1), priorphi = c(20, 1.1),
                         priorsigma = 0.1,designmatrix = "ar1")
summary(sv_model_oil, showlatent = FALSE)

sigma_oil <- sv_model_oil$latent;
sigma_matrix_oil <- matrix(unlist(sigma_oil), ncol = 100, byrow = TRUE)


num_draws_oil <- dim(sigma_matrix_oil)[1]
num_quarters_oil <- dim(sigma_matrix_oil)[2]

m_export_oil <- matrix(ncol = 4, nrow = num_quarters_oil)

for (i in 1:num_quarters_oil) {
  qq_oil = quantile(100*exp(sigma_matrix_oil[,i]/2),  probs = c(0.05, 0.5,0.95))
  m_export_oil[i,1:3]<- qq_oil
  m_export_oil[i,4] <- oil_qtrly$real_price[i]
}
m_export_oil<-data.frame(m_export_oil)

volplot(sv_model_oil, forecast = NULL, dates = oil_qtrly$date[-1])
```

Answer (score 2):

The underlying data for this plot can be found in `sv_model_oil$summary$sd` columns `c('5%', '50%', '95%')`. It also has the `mean` and `sd` (sd of the simulations I presume).

A great trick in R(Studio) you can use to figure this out is just to inspect the source. In an R console just run `volplot` *without* parens or in RStudio select "volplot" and press F2. Another approach is to execute the function step by step by first running `debug(volplot)` followed by your original command. The debugger allows you to inspect values, step forward using the command <kbd>n</kbd> and continue running using the command <kbd>c</kbd>. To stop debugging run `undebug(volplot)`.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot for the super helpful comment !